# How to change the username in Google Chrome profiles?

Tags: google-chrome

I have two profiles in my Google Chrome: Joe and Sam. I would like to rename the name of my profile into "JoeJobs" but I can't find any way to do it. I'm only getting "Manage people" and "Remove this person".

Is there any way to rename my username profile. Deleting it and re-creating it is truely ridiculous - I saved a lot of bookmarks and there's a ton of website settings saved in my profile

Comment: Web browsers questions are off-topic on this site unless they are about using a specific web app as is described on [help/on-topic]. Try [su].

Comment: Google support site has a document explaining how to do this. Have you followed these instructions? https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I just found this out after looking around for a while. this method works as of 2019-May 30th, on Chrome 74. Other versions may change how it's done.

1) Open Chrome, make sure you are on the profile you want to change the name or icon picture of.

- Change profiles by clicking on the icon on the upper right of Chrome, it is the second to last thing on upper right, just before the 3 dots / menu button.

2) Once you're the profile to edit, click on the menu (the 3 dots on upper right) and click on '**Settings**' at the bottom of the list (just above 'Help')

3) The top Settings box is for '**People**'. The third line is '**Chrome name and picture**'. Click that line.

4) You should see the settings window show 'Edit person' with a line to change the profile name and the icon. To finish and save any changes, click on the back (left pointing) arrow next to the words 'Edit person'

Answer (score 10):

A profile has both a nickname and a full name.

In Chrome Settings -> "You and Google" -> "Chrome name and picture" (i.e. `chrome://settings/manageProfile`) you can only change the full name.

In Google homepage -> "Manage your Google account" -> "Personal info" (i.e. `https://myaccount.google.com/personal-info`) you can also change the nickname.

Comment: this worked for me

Comment: this is the actual answer!

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to the Chrome Profile as shown in the dropdown menu from the current user. Like this:

Company (Client Project)

In this example "Company" is the firstname of the Google Account, which can be changed under name at: https://myaccount.google.com/personal-info

"Client Project" comes from the Chrome Profile Chrome Name and Picture at: chrome://settings/manageProfile

If you work with several companies and clients (and also potentially share Chrome Profiles to coordinate bookmarks and extensions) this naming structure helps keep all the Companies and Client Projects straight.

Answer (score 0):

(shame I can't comment yet, but this is how I solved my issue.)
If *after* going into your Google account settings and changing your name your old name is *still* being shown on your chrome profile when you click the small icon on the top right, check if sync is turned on. If it is, turn it off (then optionally back on again), and your new name will show up immediately.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).